# EventListener for identifying multiple Circles in google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My code is like this

```
var cityCircle;
for (var city in citymap) {
    populationOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    clickable:true,
    map: map,
    center: citymap[city].center,
    radius:20000,
};
 cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
}
```

where citymap is an array which contains latitude and  longitude

what I get is plenty of circles at the latitude and  longitude defined in array

what I want to do is to uniquely identify which circle is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can get that information using, for example:

```
    (function(cityCircle) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.latLng.lat() + ':' + evt.latLng.lng());

            var circleCenter = cityCircle.getCenter();
            console.log(circleCenter.lat() + ':' + circleCenter.lng());
        })
    })(cityCircle)
```

From event handler argument you get point of click, from clicked circle you can get center and other relevant information.

**Update:** [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/buwiv/1/edit)

Comment: I pasted your code at the end of my code and changes console.log with alert but I am not getting any alert.can you please tell me how to make it work?

Comment: See my example at jsbin.

Comment: please send me the link

Comment: Link is at the end of answer. Is it broken?